# jQuery hide li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've html like this. I want to only show first `li` tags and don't want to show span. How to do this with jquery?

```
   <div id="div1">
      <ul class="class2">
         <li class="class3"><span class="sfBreadcrumbNodeSeparator">/</span> </li> 
         <li class="class3"> </li> 
         <li class="class3"> </li> 
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: You have a markup error: `u1` should be `ul` (lower `L` the second).

Comment: @VisioN thanks. I editted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.class2 li').not(':first').hide();` will hide all but the first list items, `$('.class2 li:first span').hide();` will hide the span. See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/agga6/4/.

Or you can do it all in one line using `$('.class2 li:not(":first")' || '.class2 li:first span').hide();`. See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/agga6/5/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the span, you can do

```
$('.sfBreadcrumbNodeSeparator').hide()
```

or give it an id value in the markup, and select based on the id value.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use this.

```
$('.sfBreadcrumbNodeSeparator').hide();
```

or this for first li of ul

```
 $('.class2 li:first span').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
<script>
$('div#div1 ul li:first-child span').hide();   
</script>
```